# Vuetify 3 using custom theme colors in vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

So im migrating from Vue2/vuetify2 to vue3/vuetify3 and i use to be able to style my `v-card-title` like so: `v-card-title class="text-h6 primary lighten-1"`. But since moving over to vuetify3 so far i cant figure out how to do this anymore. Putting the color style in the class no longer works and so far creating a scoped class and tying to `var(--v-primary-base)` or any other combination of the color variable has not worked.

How are people doing this in the new Vuetify version?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it. Use: `class="bg-my-custom-color"`

Answer (score 0):

This is listed in the [upgrade guide](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/upgrade-guide/#theme)

> - Color classes have been renamed:
>
>   - Backgrounds have a `bg-` prefix, for example `.primary` is now `.bg-primary`.
>   - Text colors have a `text-` prefix, for example `.primary--text` is now `.text-primary`.
>   - Variants are no longer a separate class, for example `.primary--text.text--darken-1` is now `.text-primary-darken-1`.

Which means that your `class="primary lighten-1"` is now `class="bg-primary-lighten-1"`

> tying to `var(--v-primary-base)` or any other combination of the color variable has not worked

This is also in the upgrade guide, the v3 equivalent is `rgb(var(--v-theme-primary))`